# Attaching @click to array element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to add `@click="method"` to a specified element inside of an array. The elements are displayed as `li` using `v-for='item in menuItems'`

```
menuItems = [
  { title: 'test1', route: '/test1'}
  { title: 'test2', route: '/test2}
]
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
  this.menuItems.forEach((item) => {
     if(item.route === '/test1') {
      item.attr('@click', 'method')
     }
  })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
<li v-for="item in menuItems" @click="method(item)">

method: function(item) { 
    console.log(item.title);
}
```

full example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mgzyufq8/

Comment: I needed to add `@click.native=""`, now it works. Thank you.